# How do I focus to div area in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a with problem div and jquery . I need to give focus on  a div in my form  using jquery. Actually I am using auto complete , my own jquery script . It's just display the data on div when a user typed in textbox . But I can't focus to div ,don't ask me why you have to focus on DIV. But I need this. Anybody have idea?

Comment: Is DIV `focusable`? What should happen when you would focus on a div?

Comment: "don't ask me why you have to focus on DIV" is a terrible thing to say. When learning, isn't it better to understand that you're trying to do something that's not common, or worse, not right to do? I'd suggest that instead of trying to focus a div, you come up with a proper solution.

Comment: @MetalFrog Sorry. I am just testing something , then I should have to know a div is focus-able or not . First Answer solved my problem(Mathias Bynens). Anyway It's not a big deal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to focus a `div` (or any element that’s not focusable by default), you’ll need to give it `tabindex=0` first:

```
$('div') // select the element
  .prop('tabIndex', 0) // make it focusable
  .focus(); // focus it
```

Answer (score 0):

A div cannot be focused on, only editable elements can be focused on as far as I know.

It may appear focused, but I can imagine that this is a css class being added.

Find what class makes the div look focused and add it